# Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'GetNetworkCredential'

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that creates a XML file with the username and password for a SQL Server database.

Script:

```
Get-Credential –Credential (Get-Credential) |
    Export-CliXml "$FileLocation\DatabaseCredentials-$SQLServer.xml"
```

This script works file, however when I try to read the username and password from the XML file I get the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method
named 'GetNetworkCredential'.
At line:18 char:1
+ $DatabasePassword = $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Script:

```
$Credentials = Import-CliXml '$FileLocation\DatabaseCredentials-$SQLServer.xml'

$DatabaseUserName = $Credentials.UserName
$DatabasePassword = $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: Please check what's type of `$Credentials` after the importing. It seems to me that it's not `PSCredential`.

Comment: @montonero When I `Write-Host $Credentials` I get the following `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`

Comment: Use `Get-member` to make sure. I've tried your example and it's working just fine for me.

Comment: I am not sure how to use Get-Member

Comment: It's `$Credentials|Get-member`.

Comment: I get a long list of methods. None of which are `GetNetworkCredential()`. Although I am unsure what this is telling me. is the IMPORT-CLIXML not working as it should.

Comment: The code you posted does not match the error you posted. Your code should be throwing an error *"Import-Clixml : Could not find a part of the path"* b/c you put the path in single quotes (thus preventing expansion of variables). Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're facing, the [edit] your question and post *that* code along with the error you receive from *that* code.

Comment: As a side-note, running `Get-Credential -Credential (Get-Credential)` is pointless as it produces the same result as a simple `Get-Credential`.